# Sorting Angularjs ng-repeat by date

Tags: python, html, angularjs, sorting

I am relatively new to AngularJS. Could use some help

I have a table with the following info

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><span ng-click="sortType = 'first_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Referral Name</span></th>
  <th><span ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Referral Name</span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in referral | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
  <td>name</td>
  <td>date</td>
 </tr>
</tabe>
```

And the js code is as follows (after the controller connections)

```
$scope.sortType = '';
$scope.sortReverse = false;
```

This works perfectly for ascending and descending when sorting the name.

Unfortunately it works similarly in the case of date too (it is sorting alphabetically, rather than by date).

The date format I am getting from the backend(python) is in this format:

```
i["date"] = i["date"].strftime("%B %d, %Y")
September 13, 2016 <-- this format
```

I understand the mistake I made, but I am not able to find the solution for it.

How can I sort by date?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Ideally, you'd figure out a way to get a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) into the javascript and then use angular's [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for displaying it.  Note that if it's easier you can send timestamps or ISO formatted date strings and the date filter will still handle it just fine (you don't actually _need_ to convert to a Javascript Date yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd have a sortable object for date.  One candidate is an isoformatted date:

```
i["date"] = i["date"].isoformat()
```

Now sorting should work just fine but it'll display wonky.  So you'll need to use a date filter to format it on the UI:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><span ng-click="sortType = 'first_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Referral Name</span></th>
  <th><span ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Referral Name</span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in referral | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
  <td>name</td>
  <td>{{x.date | date : 'MMMM d, yyyy'}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the value you receive is type of string and therefore it is sorted alphabetically. You need to convert it into Date() beforehand. So basically what you need is to loop over the array of data you got and add a new property (or replace existing one) with a new Date object:

```
referral.forEach((ref) => {
    ref.date_obj = new Date(ref.date)
};
```

I just checked, JavaScript seems to be parsing format "September 13, 2016" pretty well.

Comment: But this _could_ be pretty browser dependent as it isn't really well standardized what formats `Date` can parse other than ISO.

Comment: Then we can reformat the date string manually to turn it into "2016-09-13". But I think it would be much easier to change the return format on the back-end instead.