# How do I sort my list of objects by an id array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort my list of arrays, but to no avail.

**The problem**: I have a list of objects however I need to sort it by an id string, which is inside an array.

JSON:

```
[{"id":2613,"name":"Aula 01","section":989},{"id":2614,"name":"Aula 02","section":989},{"id":2616,"name":"Aula 04","section":989},{"id":2617,"name":"Aula 05","section":989,},{"id":2615,"name":"3 - Aula 03","section":989}]
```

Array id sequence:

```
["2613", "2614", "2615", "2616", "2617"]
```

How to order ng-repeat or a loop in this array?

Comment: [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP if you're asking about angular?

Comment: Are you asking about sorting the object array in the order of another array with the ids in the sort order?

Comment: If this is for showing on the page with ng-repeat, then you can use [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Angularjs ng-repeat by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471200/sorting-angularjs-ng-repeat-by-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an arbitrary order of the given `id` with the sequence array, you could use an object with the order for sorting.

```js
array = [{ id: 2613, name: "Aula 01", section: 989 }, { id: 2614, name: "Aula 02", section: 989 }, { id: 2616, name: "Aula 04", section: 989 }, { id: 2617, name: "Aula 05", section: 989 }, { id: 2615, name: "3 - Aula 03", section: 989 }],
    sequence = ["2617", "2613", "2614", "2615", "2616"],
    order = {};

sequence.forEach(function (id, i) { order[id] = i + 1 });

array.sort(function (a, b) { return order[a.id] - order[b.id]; });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have the 2 arrays and the second one is the id sequence not necessarily in the order of the smallest to the largest!

Comment: I did not understand the css! If not help or comment

Comment: the sequence is in arbitrary order, like above, where the first id is greater then all following id, they are ascending, as example. the css is just to give you a greater console window on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You could sort like this `a.id-b.id` using js

```js
var arr =[{"id":2613,"name":"Aula 01","section":989},{"id":2614,"name":"Aula 02","section":989},{"id":2616,"name":"Aula 04","section":989},{"id":2617,"name":"Aula 05","section":989,},{"id":2615,"name":"3 - Aula 03","section":989}]
var res = arr.sort((a,b)=> a.id-b.id)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting with `ng-repeat` is really quite easy

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'id' ">
```

Comment: @lealceldeiro, if that is really the question for.

Comment: @lealceldeiro It is not the order of the id and yes of the array with their sequence.

Comment: @NinaScholz, you are right. I misunderstood the question. Thanks, Adriel Olivera, for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the native [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and use compare function, like this:

```
var json = [{"id":2613,"name":"Aula 01","section":989},{"id":2614,"name":"Aula 02","section":989},{"id":2616,"name":"Aula 04","section":989},{"id":2617,"name":"Aula 05","section":989,},{"id":2615,"name":"3 - Aula 03","section":989}];

var result = json.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)

console.log(result);
```

Assuming your JSON is coming from a service, it might look like this:

```
$scope.json = service.getJson().sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Or maybe:

```
service.getJson().then(function (data) {

   $scope.json = data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
});
```

Then you can just `ng-repeat` it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do this. 
1. You could write a sorting function in your controller that sorts the return object after the api is called and put in a variable to reference in angular after it has been sorted. 
2. You can use something like this: [orderBy array item value in Angular ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936078/orderby-array-item-value-in-angular-ng-repeat) on ng repeat.